# Distinguishing a pipe from a file in windows

Tags: windows, file, pipe, handle

On Unix, everything is a file, so you can use file i/o functions with pipes, files, sockets, etc.  But on windows, the api you use depends on the type of i/o HANDLE you have.

My question is: given a HANDLE how do you determine what the underlying type is?  For example, I have a HANDLE that's either real file, or a named/anonymous pipe.  I'd like to know whether PeekNamedPipe can be called on this HANDLE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `GetFileType`. Check for a return value of `FILE_TYPE_PIPE`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364960(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Without trying to be silly.
Call it. If you get an error code back saying its the wrong type of thing... then you know.

A similar principal is relevent when trying to see if the user has the rights to open a file. Its possible to try and fully reverse engineer and re-implement the logic the file system goes through to test the ACLs. Or, just try and open it.

Comment: This could cause hangs or SEH exceptions to get thrown under certain circumstances. I would avoid calling whatever on a named pipe handle and assume that the behavior will be just fine.